# Word to describe something that has an ending

Tags: single-word-requests

How to say that something has an ending in one word? I am looking for the opposite of endless.

Comment: Limited, as well as finite (like Glor mentioned), both work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *finite* comes to mind:

> 1 b : having a limited nature or existence
>   // *finite* beings

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finite))

It's the opposite of [*infinite*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infinite), the 'formal'/'scientific' version of endless.

Comment: A ring would be finite, but has no end.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will depend on the kind of thing that has an ending.

Finite works for some things. A finite series, for example, would be a series that has an end. But a finite ring might not have an end.

A ring that was changed to have an end might be a broken ring. It might also apply to things like promises or contracts. A broken contract is ended.

Limited also will work in some cases. A limited engagement would be an engagement that has a specific or anticipated end. A limited life span indicates mortality. But a globe has limits and, just as the ring, no end.

Terminated works in some cases. Or variations such as terminating. A life can be terminated. A journey can terminate at a destination and we might say "terminating in New Jersey" for example.